# Error in Doctrine PHP relation -> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have this two models

```
{
    class Email extends Doctrine_Record
    {
        public function setTableDefinition()
        {
            $this->setTableName('email');
            $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
                 'type' => 'integer',
                 'length' => 4,
                 'fixed' => false,
                 'unsigned' => false,
                 'primary' => true,
                 'autoincrement' => true,
                 ));
            $this->hasColumn('nombre', 'string', 40, array(
                 'type' => 'string',
                 'length' => 40,
                 'fixed' => false,
                 'unsigned' => false,
                 'primary' => false,
                 'notnull' => true,
                 'autoincrement' => false,
                 ));
            $this->hasColumn('email', 'string', 90, array(
                 'type' => 'string',
                 'length' => 90,
                 'fixed' => false,
                 'unsigned' => false,
                 'primary' => false,
                 'notnull' => true,
                 'autoincrement' => false,
                 ));
            $this->hasColumn('estado', 'integer', 1, array(
                 'type' => 'integer',
                 'length' => 1,
                 'fixed' => false,
                 'unsigned' => false,
                 'primary' => false,
                 'default' => '1',
                 'notnull' => true,
                 'autoincrement' => false,
                 ));
            $this->hasColumn('borrado', 'integer', 1, array(
                 'type' => 'integer',
                 'length' => 1,
                 'fixed' => false,
                 'unsigned' => false,
                 'primary' => false,
                 'default' => '0',
                 'notnull' => true,
                 'autoincrement' => false,
                 ));
            $this->hasColumn('created_at', 'timestamp', null, array(
                 'type' => 'timestamp',
                 'fixed' => false,
                 'unsigned' => false,
                 'primary' => false,
                 'notnull' => true,
                 'autoincrement' => false,
                 ));
            $this->hasColumn('updated_at', 'timestamp', null, array(
                 'type' => 'timestamp',
                 'fixed' => false,
                 'unsigned' => false,
                 'primary' => false,
                 'notnull' => true,
                 'autoincrement' => false,
                 ));
        }

        public function setUp()
        {
            parent::setUp();

            $this->hasMany('Grupo as Grupos', array(
                    'refClass' => 'EmailGrupo',
                    'local' => 'email_id',
                    'foreign' => 'grupo_id'));

            $this->hasMany('Envio as Envios', array(
                    'local' => 'email_id',
                    'foreign' => 'envio_id',
                    'refClass' => 'EnvioEmail'));
        }

        //setters   
        public function setId($id) { $this->_set('id', $id); }
        public function setNombre($nombre) { $this->_set('nombre', $nombre); }
        public function setEmail($email) { $this->_set('email', $email); }
        public function setEstado($estado) { $this->_set('estado', $estado); }
        public function setBorrado($borrado) { $this->_set('borrado', $borrado); }

        //getters
        public function getId() { return $this->_get('id'); }
        public function getNombre() { return $this->_get('nombre'); }
        public function getEmail() { return $this->_get('email'); }
        public function getEstado() { return $this->_get('estado'); }
        public function getBorrado() { return $this->_get('borrado'); }
        public function getGrupos() { return $this->_get('Grupos'); }
        public function getEnvios() { return $this->_get('Envios'); }

        public function delete(){
            $this->setBorrado(1);
            $this->save();
        }


    }

}

{

    class EmailGrupo extends Doctrine_Record
    {
        public function setTableDefinition()
        {
            $this->setTableName('email_grupo');
            $this->hasColumn('email_id', 'integer', 4, array(
                 'type' => 'integer',
                 'length' => 4,
                 'fixed' => false,
                 'unsigned' => false,
                 'primary' => true,
                 'autoincrement' => false,
                 ));
            $this->hasColumn('grupo_id', 'integer', 4, array(
                 'type' => 'integer',
                 'length' => 4,
                 'fixed' => false,
                 'unsigned' => false,
                 'primary' => true,
                 'autoincrement' => false,
                 ));
        }

        public function setUp()
        {
            parent::setUp();

            $this->hasOne('Email', array(
                 'local' => 'email_id',
                 'foreign' => 'id'));

            $this->hasOne('Grupo', array(
                 'local' => 'grupo_id',
                 'foreign' => 'id'));


        }

        // setters
        public function setEmailId($email_id) { $this->_set('email_id', $email_id); }
        public function setGrupoId($grupo_id) { $this->_set('grupo_id', $grupo_id); }


        // getters
        public function getEmailId() { return $this->_get('email_id'); }
        public function getGrupoId() { return $this->_get('grupo_id'); }
    }

}
```

When I try to get the "Grupos" executing `$email->getGrupos();` I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception'
>   with message    'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown
>   column 'e.id' in 'on clause'' in F:\Proyectos\Flash
>   Moda\code\application\helpers\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\Connection.php on
>   line 1083.

I log the queries and I get:

> SELECT g.id AS g_*id, g.nombre AS g*_nombre, g.borrado AS g__borrado,
>   g.created_at AS g__created_at, g.updated_at AS g__updated_at,
>   e.email_id AS e__email_id, e.grupo_id AS e__grupo_id FROM grupo g LEFT
>   JOIN email_grupo e ON g.id = e.id WHERE (e.email_id IN (?))

Why right side of the on in join are wrong? thanks

**UPDATE**: add grupo model and how I get $email

```
class Grupo extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('grupo');
        $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 4,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('nombre', 'string', 40, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => 40,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('borrado', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 1,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'default' => '0',
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('created_at', 'timestamp', null, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('updated_at', 'timestamp', null, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->actAs('Timestampable');      

       $this->hasMany('Email as Emails', array(
                'local' => 'id',
                'foreign' => 'grupo_id',
                'refClass' => 'EmailGrupo'
            )
         );

         $this->hasMany('Envio as Envios', array(
                'local' => 'id',
                'foreign' => 'grupo_id',
                'refClass' => 'EnvioGrupo'
            )
         ); 
    }

    //setters
    public function setId($id) { $this->_set('id', $id); }
    public function setNombre($nombre) { $this->_set('nombre', $nombre); }
    public function setBorrado($borrado) { $this->_set('borrado', $borrado); }

    // getters
    public function getId() { return $this->_get('id'); }
    public function getNombre() { return $this->_get('nombre'); }
    public function getBorrado() { return $this->_get('borrado'); }

    public function delete(){
        $this->setBorrado(1);
        $this->save();
    }

}

$email = Doctrine::getTable('Email')->find($this->uri->segment(4,0));
```

Comment: Can you post the way you get `$email` var, and one more model - `Grupo`, looks like in that model there is an error.

Comment: I update the question with the definition of Grupo and how I get $meail

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the grupo model, this is the  correct model:

```
class Grupo extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('grupo');
        $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 4,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('nombre', 'string', 40, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => 40,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('borrado', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 1,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'default' => '0',
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('created_at', 'timestamp', null, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('updated_at', 'timestamp', null, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->actAs('Timestampable');      

        $this->hasMany('Email as Emails', array(
                'local' => 'grupo_id',
                'foreign' => 'email_id',
                'refClass' => 'EmailGrupo'
            )
         );

        $this->hasMany('Envio as Envios', array(
                'local' => 'grupo_id',
                'foreign' => 'envio_id',
                'refClass' => 'EnvioGrupo'
            )
         ); 
    }

    //setters
    public function setId($id) { $this->_set('id', $id); }
    public function setNombre($nombre) { $this->_set('nombre', $nombre); }
    public function setBorrado($borrado) { $this->_set('borrado', $borrado); }

    // getters
    public function getId() { return $this->_get('id'); }
    public function getNombre() { return $this->_get('nombre'); }
    public function getBorrado() { return $this->_get('borrado'); }


}
```

I hange the lines defining the relaicon with Email.